# Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

I am building project with TFS through MSBuild Task.
Though it is getting build with Zero error Task is Failing with One single line message "Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'."

Error Log -
[image]

I will be very Thankful if someone can help me to find the solution for this.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the msbuild return of 1 in the middle of thread is a real compilation failure (msbuild returns 1 on valid failure). So try troubleshooting/debugging or whatever you have as your test environment to fix the error.

Comment: Yes..as Project is compiling with Zero errors and then this Error coming.That is why I have attached Logs of this failure happening with _task configuration Powershell files of Build Agent to find out what this PowerShell failure.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the Issue. My solution is having multiple Projects and one of them has the reference of COM object which is not working with msbuild.exe as it requires Visual Studio build task(In my case VS build task is not compatible) to deal with Visual studio switches(later I found we can use all switches of Visual studio with MSBuild command line).

And though it was failing why **Error count Zero** showing is you may find here -  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1204997/Post-build-event-exit-code-error#NewEntryGroup

Actual Build wasn't the success. there was an issue resolving COMobject reference and could not exit task with the exit code 0.

That is all. I have just Increased verbosity level to Diagnostics and I got the problem.